# WPF ComboBox: Trouble converting back-and-forth of Selected Item (Works in all cases, but this one.)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, combobox

**BACKGROUND**

I have a simple class that I've created that I use to population my collections that are assigned to my `ItemSource` property on my combo boxes.  I use this when the source is a list of enumerations that need a good descriptor text.

```
public class BindableEnumerationItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private T _item;

    public BindableEnumerationItem(T item, string displayText)
    {
        _item = item;
        _displayText = displayText;
    }

    private string _displayText;
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get { return _displayText; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _displayText)
            {
                _displayText = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayText"));
            }
        }
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set
        {
            _item = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty straight forward.

Next, in my ViewModels I assign to List objects my lists of `BindableEnumerationItem` objects for my associated enumeration values.  Something like this is often defined in my initialization code:

```
//DisplayAccountTypes is a property that I'll use as an ItemSource
DisplayAccountTypes = new List<BindableEnumerationItem<DisplayAccountType>>();
DisplayAccountTypes.Add(new BindableEnumerationItem<DisplayAccountType>(DisplayAccountType.Windows, "Windows Credentials"));
DisplayAccountTypes.Add(new BindableEnumerationItem<DisplayAccountType>(DisplayAccountType.SQL, "SQL Server"));
DisplayAccountTypes.Add(new BindableEnumerationItem<DisplayAccountType>(DisplayAccountType.Linux, "Linux"));
```

Next, I create a `ComboBox` in my xaml.  Assume that the above initialization snippet is from within a View Model that is the `DataContext` object on my xaml object.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboboxAccountType" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayAccountTypes}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDisplayAccountType}"
    DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"
    SelectedValuePath="Item" >
```

FYI, `SelectedDisplayAccountType` is specifically an enumeration property on my VM.

**PROBLEM**

Now, I've used this setup time and time again.  This has worked fine. I can toggle the combo box values and it updates on the backend.  However, on my most recent implementation I've been getting the following errors when I attempt to use the current combo box.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert
>   `` MyApp.ViewModel.Helpers.BindableEnumerationItem`1[MyApp.ViewModel.DisplayAccountType] ``
>   from type `` BindableEnumerationItem`1 `` to type
>   `MyApp.ViewModel.DisplayAccountType` for 'en-US' culture with default
>   conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.
>   NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: EnumConverter
>   cannot convert from
>   `` MyApp.ViewModel.Helpers.BindableEnumerationItem`1[[MyApp.ViewModel.DisplayAccountType ``,
>   MyApp.ViewModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]].    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object
>   value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type
>   destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean isForward)'
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value
>   `` MyApp.ViewModel.Helpers.BindableEnumerationItem`1[MyApp.ViewModel.DisplayAccountType] ``
>   (type `` BindableEnumerationItem`1 ``).
>   BindingExpression:Path=SelectedDisplayAccountType;
>   DataItem='CredentialsManagementViewModel' (HashCode=58609412); target
>   element is 'ComboBox' (Name='ComboboxAccountType'); target property is
>   'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')
>   NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: EnumConverter
>   cannot convert from
>   MyApp.ViewModel.Helpers.BindableEnumerationItem`1[[MyApp.ViewModel.DisplayAccountType,
>   MyApp.ViewModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]].    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type
>   destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean isForward)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type
>   type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter
>   converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter,
>   CultureInfo culture)'

This has stumped me for hours.  I'm not doing anything special.  In fact, the above code is the broken production code.  I could copy & paste another example of my use of this setup, however, they are pretty much the EXACT same thing except name/values are different for each property/selectors respective context.

I understand that these errors are saying but, in regards to what I'm doing, they don't make sense.  I'm not trying to convert from a `BindableEnumerationItem` to my enumeration.  I should be binding to the `Item` property on my `BindableEnumerationItem` which should certainly be my enumeration.

Maybe I just need a second pair of eyes, but I can't spot the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: I guess the problem is that your `DisplayAccountType` is not part of `BindableEnumerationItem` because you are using a generic type. If,instead of `public T Item` you use `public DisplayAccountType Item`,I think it should work.You may try it to discard this.

Comment: I don't think the generic approach is a problem at all. I use the same. Have you tried to use `SelectedValue`instead o `SelectedItem`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Mat ...and when you see it, it's so obvious.  This is why I needed those second pair of eyes.  In all other locations, I was using `SelectedValue` rather than `SelectedItem`.  Changing the reference has fixed my application.  Answer the question below to get the answer mark.  Thanks again.

Comment: @will see my last comment.  Mat spotted the real issue.

Comment: Aaah, good on ya.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your items are of type `BindableEnumerationItem<DisplayAccountType>`, but you bind the `SelectedItem` to a property of type `DisplayAccountType`.

There are four solutions:

1. Use `SelectedIndex` instead.
2. Use `SelectedValue` instead.
3. Make `DisplayAccountTypes` to be a collection of `DisplayAccountType` items.
4. Make `SelectedDisplayAccountType` to be of type `BindableEnumerationItem<DisplayAccountType>`.